# Entity Framework 7 and SQLite typeless (aka sql_variant in SQL Server) column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net

In a previous project I used SQLite database and in one of the tables I had a column with undefined type so this column was able to store any type (datetimes was in datetime format, decimals in decimal format and etc). To retrieve data I used ado.net.

In current case EF code first fits better to my needs. So I tried to do it with EF 7.0.0-rc1-final but it throws exception on adding migration.

So is there any way to create entity with property of type object and update database using ef?

Comment: That sounds like a **horribly bad idea** in any relational database. You should **always** use the most appropriate datatype - and `SQL_Variant` is definitely a **BIG NO-NO!** - see this [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) for more info

Comment: @marc_s, not in my case. For example I will have entity with 50 + properties. Mostly all are nullable. Amount of properties can be changed depends on user input or extended by third-party plugins. I can't know type of all that properties. You can imagine it like dictionary<string, object> .